# Split list<t> into files by n number

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, streamwriter

I have a a list that contains over 4000 items.  These items get passed through a method that returns a XML block in the form of a string.  I then need to use StreamWriter to write these strings to a XML file.  There is a limit of only being allowed 1000 "strings" per file.

```
int elementCount = 0;
int fileNumber = 1;
string fileName = "C:\\test\\" + DateTime.Now().toString("ddMMyyyy") + "_0" +fileNumber + ".xml";

Do 
{ 
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    foreach (Vehicles v in vehicles)
    {
        if (elementCount != 1000)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(ConvertCode.ToXml(v));
            elementCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Close();
            fileNumber++;
            sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            elementCount = 0;
            sw.WriteLine(ConvertCode.ToXml(v));
            elementCount++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
while (elementCount < 1000)
```

So at the end of this code i am expecting that there will be 5 files.  4 files with 1000 items and 1 other file with the balance of items. At them moment i am only getting one file that seems to have the first 500 items and the last 500 items.

I know there must be something wrong with my looping structure, but i can't seem to work out how to get a successful structure.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that file name is wrong. In `else` block you have:

```
sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
```

As you can see, you create new file without changing file name to new (for new number). I suppose it should be:

```
var currDate = DateTime.Now().toString("ddMMyyyy");
string fileName = "C:\\test\\" 
                    + currDate + "_0"
                    + fileNumber + ".xml";
....
else
{
    sw.Close();
    fileNumber++;
    fileName = "C:\\test\\" 
                +  currDate 
                + "_0" + fileNumber 
                + ".xml";
    sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    elementCount = 0;
    sw.WriteLine(ConvertCode.ToXml(v));
    elementCount++;
    // break;
    // that break is not neccessary
}
```

What's more, you have used `break` which breaks whole loop (breaks foreach), and causes iterating vehicles again (from beginning). It's not neccessary I suppose.

The last thing - outside `do...while` is not necessesary also, I don't see a purpose of it.

**BTW**
It's nice algorithm to parallelize:

```
var list = vehicles as IList<Vehicle> ?? vehicles.ToList();
if (!list.Any()) return;

var currDate = DateTime.Now().toString("ddMMyyyy");

var groups = list.Count / 1000;
Parallel.For(0, groups + 1, groupNo => {

  var fileName  = "C:\\test\\" 
                +  currDate 
                + "_0" + groupNo
                + ".xml";
  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
  {
      var limit = Math.Min(groupNo * 1000 + 1000, list.Count);
      for (var i = groupNo * 1000, i < limit; i++)
      {
          var v = list[i];
          sw.WriteLine(ConvertCode.ToXml(v));
      }
  }

});
```

Comment: I took your advice about recreating the "fileName" after 1000 lines and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

While my code looks nothing like yours, the fact of recreating the fileName that you suggested fixed what code i did have.  Will remember the small things like that for next time.

```
foreach (Vehicle v in vehicles)
{
    if (elementCount < 1000)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(CreateVehicleXmlElement.BuildElement(v));
        elementCount++;
    }
    else if (elementCount == 1000)
    {
         writer.Close();
         fileNumber++;
         elementCount = 0;
         baseName = "c:\\test\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy") + "_0" + fileNumber + ".";
         writer = new StreamWriter(baseName + "xml");
         writer.WriteLine("This is the header that will be filled in later");
         writer.WriteLine(CreateVehicleXmlElement.BuildElement(v));
         elementCount++;
    }
}
writer.Close();
```